# Stacking septic leach fields

Tags: septic

I am getting ready to build a house and the state code is 100 ft of leach field per bedroom.  Due to the size of the lot I am limited to where I can place the house due to the leach field length code.  I was told by a neighbor that I could stack the leach field lines.  I have not been able to find any specific information on that stacking suggestion. Is something like this even a feasible option?

Comment: Since you are talking about State codes, it would help to know your State...

Comment: Sounds highly suspect, but the way to find a system that works in your area on your lot is to consult with a professional in the design of septic systems. In most states that is required - you can build it yourself, but someone licensed and qualified has to design it, generally after a percolation test to evaluate the soil drainage. If it's really the case that your state simply calls for 100 feet of line per bedroom, perhaps they don't believe in such things; I'd advise it anyway, getting it wrong stinks and getting it right is trouble-free for decades (with appropriate maintenance.)

Comment: Ask your local jurisdiction. They have to approve it anyway and they usually like helping people

Comment: It probably doesn't specify a single continuous 100 foot leach line. I can only assume that two 50 footers would be acceptable for a single bedroom. If your land is so constrained that your house placement is severely affected by the septic system then I can only imagine the headache of installing a garage in the future or other structures.

Answer (score 1):

I'll echo the other comments, in a slightly modified manner. The idea of 100 feet continuous is not necessarily a valid interpretation. 4 x 25 still provides 100 feet. Accordingly, stacking can refer to horizontal placement, rather than one atop the other. This was confirmed by my contractor upon a recent field replacement. Depending on your local codes, the 100 feet doesn't have to be monolithic. If the lot requires it, a pair of 25 footers side-by-side linked to another location containing another pair would still qualify.